# Prove the the uniform, $L^1$ and $L^2$ norms are not equivalent.

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Two norms $||\cdot||_1$ and $||\cdot||_2$ on a vector space are equivalent if there exist constants $c_1$, $c_2$ such that

$$c_1||x||_1 \le ||x||_2 \le c_2||x||_1$$

for all $x\in X$ (I have proved that this is a equivalence relation ) .

So I know that $||f||_1 \le ||f||_2 \le ||f||_u$ so since I don't want that this norms are equivalent I want to do this by contradiction.

So I assumed that there were constants such that :

$$c_{1} (\int{|f(x)|}))<(\int{|f(x)|^{2}})^{1/2})<c_{2} (\int{|f(x)|}))$$

But this tell us that $$(\int{|f(x)|^{2}}))<c_{2}^{2}(\int{|f(x)|}^{2})$$

The thing is that how can I use something else than Jensen's inequality to prove this? And what can I do to prove that the uniform norm is not equivalent to the other two? , because there I have to prove that no lower bound can be accepted.

Thanks a lot for your help un advance :) .

Comment: What is $X$ here?

Comment: Those norms are equivalent sometimes. Specify which vector space of functions you're talking about.

Comment: C([0,1]) continous functions in 0 to 1

Comment: Thanks a lot but we havent seen measure theory . :)

Comment: What is $\|f\|_u$?

Comment: It is the uniform norm defined as $||f(x)||_{u}=max|f(x)|$

Comment: I am back in the discussion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $f_n(x) = (n+1)x^n,$ then $\|f_n\|_1 = 1, \|f_n\|_2 =(n+1)/\sqrt {2n+1}, \|f_n\|_u = n+1.$

Comment: I dont understand this answer could you elaborate more in this please :)

Comment: n positive right?

Comment: $n=1,2,\dots $ The example shows $\|f_n\|_2/\|f_n\|_1, \|f_n\|_u/\|f_n\|_1, \|f_n\|_u/\|f_n\|_2$ all $\to \infty.$ Hence these three norms are not equivalent.

Comment: Ok so is n fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Jensen's inequality?  Oh geeze, I'm a bad analyst, so I can never remember something like that.  Here's a trick you might try.  Suppose that there is a constant $c > 0$ so that $||f||_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)} \le c ||f||_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)}$.

Let's make the change of variables $x \to \epsilon x $ for some $\epsilon > 0$.  That is, let's let $y = \epsilon x$.

Notice then that $\int |f(x)| dx = \int |f(\epsilon^{-1}y)| \epsilon^{-n} dy = \epsilon^{-n} ||f_{\epsilon^{-1}}||_{L^1}$

So, $||f||_{L^1} = \epsilon^{-n} ||f_{\epsilon^{-1}}||_{L^1} \le \epsilon^{-n}c ||f_{\epsilon^{-1}}||_{L^2} $

A similar computation will show that $||f_{\epsilon^{-1}}||_{L^2}|| = \epsilon^{\frac{n}{2}} ||f||_{L^2} $

Plugging that it in, we get that $||f||_{L^1} \le  \epsilon^{-\frac{n}{2}} c ||f||_{L^2}$

That holds for any $\epsilon > 0$.  Can you finish the contradiction?

**Edit**:

To elaborate a bit (skip this if you don't want to see the solution).  Arguing as in the other direction, if a constant $c > 0$ existed so that $||f||_{L^2} \le c ||f||_{L^1}$, we'd have for all $\epsilon > 0$ that

$||f||_{L^2} = \epsilon^{-\frac{n}{2}} ||f_{\epsilon^{-1}}||_{L^2} \le c \epsilon^{-\frac{n}{2}} ||f_{\epsilon^{-1}}||_{L^1} = c\epsilon^{\frac{n}{2}}||f||_{L^1} $

Now let $\epsilon \to 0$ and deduce a contradiction from an $f$ which isn't $0$ ae.

The point of these arguments is that $L^p$ norms scale under the scaling operator $\tau_{\epsilon}$ defined by $\tau_{\epsilon}f(x) = f(\epsilon x)$.  In particular, we should get that $|| \tau_{\epsilon}f||_{L^p} = \epsilon^{-\frac{n}{p}} ||f||_{L^p}$.  Were the norms equivalent, this operator would have to scale both norms proportionally in order to maintain the equivalence.  But that doesn't happen.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot :) let me try it. And for tje other cases, have you got something ?

Comment: Use the exact same scaling argument for the other and limit $\epsilon$ in a different direction.  This is a pretty common trick to use, by the way.  When you're trying to prove an $L^p \to L^q$ bound like this, initially use a scaling argument to test what the possible values for $p$ and $q$ are such that a bound can actually exist.

Comment: I've added an edit to explain some, but I encourage you to try your hand at the other inequality before reading my edit :)

Comment: Ok, let me try it, and this argument is the same to compare the uniform norm with the other two?

Comment: By the uniform norm I assume you mean the $L^{\infty}$ norm?  If so then yes.  Taking $p = \infty$ we'll get that $||\tau_{\epsilon} f||_{L^{\infty}} = ||f||_{L^{\infty}}$ (which matches up with what I have for $p = \infty$).  The $L^{\infty}$ norm really doesn't care about scale.  It's all about absolutes.

In response to your comment, yes, the two norms we're talking about are the same (at least for continuous $f$).

Comment: No, is this one max|f(x)| for x in 0 1

Comment: Why $\epsilon^{-n}$?

Comment: I'm working over $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Take whatever $n$ you're using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26905/discussion-between-guest-and-user162343).

Comment: I am back in the discussion

Comment: The integrals are from zero to one right ?

Comment: It doesn't matter; though if you're working on $[0,1]$, we take $n = 1$.