# Find a example where $ \bar B_\epsilon(x) \not\subset \overline{B_\epsilon(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to solve the following:

Let $\bar B_\epsilon(x)$ be the closed ball with center $x$ and radius $\epsilon>0$, and $\overline{B_\epsilon(x)}$ the closure of the open ball $B_\epsilon(x)$. Then $\overline{B_\epsilon(x)} \subset \bar B_\epsilon(x)$. Give an example where $\bar B_\epsilon(x) \not\subset \overline{B_\epsilon(x)}$

I was triying to think geometrically in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with the taxicab norm or euclidean, but I don't have in fact perspective of what $\overline{B_\epsilon(x)}$ is, so Can someone help me to find the example please?

Comment: have you tried the discrete metric?

Comment: the one that is zero if x=x and 1 otherwise right?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need a metric space other than $\Bbb R^n$ under the usual metric.

How about the space $X = [0,1] \cup \{2\}$, with $x = \epsilon = 1$?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but with which metric?

Comment: The usual metric on $\Bbb R$. Notice that my metric space is no longer the whole of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: ok let me see, if I got problems can I tell you?

Comment: Feel free to comment here, and I'll get back to you as soon as I can

Comment: They are equal right ?

Comment: @user162343 Start here: what is $B_1(1)$, *within the space $X$*?

Comment: (0,1) right ? And the closure is adding 0, and 2

Comment: First, you should have $B_1(1) = (0,1]$.  And why do you think that $2$ should be in the closure? The set $[0,1]$ is already closed.

Comment: I thought that because I the definition of the ball is ${x \in X: d(x,1)<1}$ so 0,2 arent there, but I wasn't sure about 2 as an accumulation point.

Comment: So, you weren't sure if $2$ was an accumulation point of $(0,1]$ (in the space $X$).  What's the definition of an accumulation point?  Does $2$ fit this definition?

Comment: Also, I think you would agree that $2$ would not be an accumulation point of [0,1) if we were considering $[0,1)$ as a subset of the metric space $\Bbb R$.  Why should that change for our space $X$ when we're using the same metric?

Comment: Right, is a point such that it has ainfinite number of points of the set, so 2 doe not fit :), So what we have is that closed ball$=X$ and the closure of the ball is $[0,1]$, and we are done :)

Comment: Am I right with the above comment?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "it has ainfinite number of points of the set".  But yes: $[0,1]$ is the closure of the open ball.

Comment: So in the space $X$, we have that the closed ball is $X$, and the closure is $[0,1]$ :) so the example is done right? :), but the thing is why the open ball is $(0,1]$

Comment: Ok, I got it :) 1 is the center, and zero it at distance exactly one from 1 so it does not hold the requirements.

Comment: So that is all right?

Comment: Yes, that's all correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :), can you help with any of this questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394894/prove-the-the-uniform-l1-and-l2-norms-are-not-equivalent   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395175/proving-that-if-b1-delta0-subset-b-120-and-b-epsilon20-subset-b-1  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395229/in-mathbbrn-the-norms-induced-by-inner-products-are-equivalent/1395866?noredirect=1#comment2841975_1395866